# Trouble overriding BuildDependsOn in C# project

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm trying to follow the docs here -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2017 -- to get a simple Target added to the build pipeline of a .NET Core project file. However, I'm doing something wrong but just cannot see it.

I've taken a simple 'Hello World' project file, added a simple target that just prints a message, and redefined `BuildDependsOn` as suggested by the docs to get:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

    <BuildDependsOn>
      Target1;
      $(BuildDependsOn)
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Target1">
    <Message Text="Running Target1" Importance="high" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The message does not print when I try to 'Build' this project with either msvc2017 or the dotnet CLI ("dotnet build -c Release Hello.csproj").

When I use msbuild to see the fully preprocessed project I can clearly see the definition of the `BuildDependsOn` property. I'm not sure why my redefinition isn't taking. I've also tried the same with `RebuildDependsOn` with the same non-effect.

Any suggestions? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 7):

The reason things are not working as you would expect is because you have an SDK-style project: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`.

Note that this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

is equivalent to this:

```xml
<Project>
  <!-- Implicit top import -->
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Implicit bottom import -->
  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
</Project>
```

The implicit import of `Sdk.targets` at the end of your project overwrites your definition of `BuildDependsOn`.

You can instead explicitly add the imports and then add your definition of `BuildDependsOn` after the `Sdk.targets` import.

```xml
<Project>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Target1">
    <Message Text="Running Target1" Importance="high" />
  </Target>

  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      Target1;
      $(BuildDependsOn)
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

See [How to: Extend the Visual Studio build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process) and [How to: Use MSBuild project SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk).

Answer (score 4):

A method that I prefer for adding a build target that depends something else is the `BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets`.
Documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2017

It's just a lot simpler I think, and I might add has less XML.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Target1" AfterTargets="Build" >
    <Message Text="Running Target1" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get it working with something like that. Just seemed really weird to me that the mechanism spelled out in the "How to Extend the Build Process" page doesn't seem to work. So, I figure that I must just be missing something, but can't see what.

Comment: @ddneilson What part of the "How to Extend the Build Process" does not seem to work? Did you see the comment in that documentation related to SDK-style projects?